# Binary serialization in WCF NetTCPBinding

Tags: wcf, strongly-typed-dataset, nettcpbinding

I have currently several WCF Services in .Net 3.5  which communicates with clients through a NetTCP Binding. We switched from WsHTTP bindings to NetTCP to reduce data traffic between client and server (NetTCP har binary encoded transfer).

We are not satisfied with the results (only 30% reduce in our tests), and want to use a binary serializer instead of the default xml serialization of object.

Will this reduce the payload even more? How do I implement binary serialization in the WCF? We use typed datasets as objects for transfer..

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely no sarcasm intended but you should seriously consider using plain objects for the service's data contracts instead of Dataset. The strongly typed Dataset object can be very complex (just look at the code behind) and any serialization of it will be pretty hefty, size-wise. NetTcpBinding already uses an binary serializer which should produce a smaller payload. As an alternative if you're trying to create a query-able/flexible service layer, look at using a [resource-based service architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) instead.

If think you can improve on Microsoft's binary encoder for the netTcpBinding, look at the sample code referenced in this [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx) to get started.

Comment: hello and thanks. The project is completely locked to using strongly typed datasets, so that's not an option. Are you sure NetTCPBinding uses a binary serializer? I know the serialized objects are transferred with binary encoding, but I thought the objects were serialized normally (xml)?

Comment: I don't have time right now to verify this but I believe that the netTcpBinding uses a **binary** XML serialization format [documented in this MSDN post.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219210(v=PROT.10).aspx) Definitely review that doc if you are thinking of to rolling your own serialization format. This [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/29/wcf-extensibility-icontractbehavior.aspx) will get you started down that route. Best of luck to you!!